# Stata: Difference-in-Difference model with time variant treatment?

Tags: regression, stata, fixed-effects-model, difference-in-difference

I want to measure the effect that a treatment (merger) has on firms (y). Therefore, I have panel-data for 6 years (2010-2015), consisting of about 1,500 firms. There are 100 firms that are somehow involved in a merger. After matching and weighting the two groups, I want to run a DID (difference in differences) analysis in Stata to make differences visible. The problem is, that there is not a fixed year in which the merger took place. That means, that some mergers took place 2011, some 20013 and some 2014.

My plan was to use the `xtdidreg` function to determine fixed effects and run the analysis. But I am wondering, if the `didreg` command is appropriate to analyse time variant treatments. That is the reason I am asking here.

I would appreciate if anyone could assess these setup and, if necessary, recommend an alternative approach.

Thanks in advance!